# Stop images from being displayed on the front-end of the site

Tags: posts, images, attachments

I run a store with woocommerce on Wordpress, however there is an image called 'basket.png', and for some reason it has taken the link /basket on the site.

Is there a way to disable all of the images' on the front-end, and only have them viewable from their direct paths?

I want to disable:

/%image_name%
and /?attachment_id=%image_id%

So that all of the permalinks for the images are restored and I can use them for my site.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want to happen.  Do you want the links to be disabled so nothing happens when you click on them or do you want 404 errors when someone tries to go to one of those links?

Comment: @GentlemanMax I either want to disable them, so 404, then I want to be able to use their parmalinks for pages. If not I want to change their permalink to /image/%image-name%/